# Make the $\sigma$−algebra of a probability space smaller

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am new to advanced probability and I want to have a better understanding of measure/probability spaces. I took the following exercise : you roll a die three times in a row. Write down the probability space $(Ω, F, \mathbb P)$ that describes all possible outcomes of this random experiment. Now, suppose you don't want to know about everything in life : find the smallest $\sigma$−algebra $G$ such that the events in this $\sigma$−algebra can distinguish between the outcomes of the first dice.

For all possible outcomes, I took $Ω:=\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb N^3 \lvert a,b,c \in \{1,\cdots,6\}\}$ for example $(1,3,6) \in Ω$; and the $\sigma$−algebra $F:=P(Ω)$.
For the second question question they are asking, I struggle to see what $\sigma$−algebra I need to take that gives only information about the first dice. In my vision of things, the elements of Ω are triplets and they will necessarily give us three-dices informations. I think that a concrete visualization of this case can make me understand this new probability approach that is different from the high school one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma$-Algebra is a system of sets satisfiying certain conditions. The maximal $\sigma$-Algebra you can use is the power set of $\Omega$. But now you are looking for a minimal $\sigma$-Algebra that contains events for each outcome of dice 1. What you can choose is for example the $\sigma$-Algebra created by the events $\{k\}\times\{1,\ldots,6\}^2$ with $1\leq k \leq 6$. It is easy to show that this $\sigma$-algebra is minimal.

Comment: In fact, it's like being blind to the outcomes of the second and third throw...

Comment: Please check the comment I wrote under @Ian's answer

Comment: The $\sigma$-Algebra contains sets, not triplets. And this $\sigma$-Algebra is built by sets like $\{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(1,1,5),(1,1,6),(1,2,1),\ldots,(1,6,6)\}$. Note that this set always has $1$ for the first position, but every possible combination for the others. So this event has full information about the first dice, but no imformation about the others.

Comment: @Lazy ok I got it now thanks ! Just to be sure, the probability measure (if the dice is normal) would be $\mathbb P(\{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),\ldots,(1,6,6)\}) = \frac16$, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the elements of $\Omega$ are triplets; the point is that the *events* of this sub-$\sigma$-algebra will contain *all* the triplets with a particular value of the first roll fixed, so knowing that the roll was in one of these events gives you no information about the other two rolls. Thus you have the trivial elements $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ as well as $\{ (a_0,b,c) : b,c=1,2\dots,6 \}$ for each $a_0=1,2,\dots,6$, and then unions of those.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid but I think I am missing something... the new $\sigma$−algebra you are giving will contain elements like (1,2,2) and (1,2,3) etc so for me it does distinguish the 2nd and 3rd rolls, moreover I feel like their unions will end up giving us the power set of $Ω$...

Comment: @John For example one of the events is $\{ 1 \} \times \{ 1,\dots,6 \} \times \{ 1,\dots,6 \}$. If I know $(a,b,c)$ is in that event then I don't know anything about the second or third rolls. The unions still have this same property that all of the possible cases of the second and third roll are in every nonempty event.